# What is the Eclipse flaw with "duplicate filenames" when working with orientation?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

In Android to support multiple orientations you have different directories `/res/layout-land` & `/res/layout-port`. I was reading something that said there is an Eclipse flaw with "duplicate filenames". What is the flaw and what is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: where did you read that? any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: @thinksteep I read about it on a side in some 3rd Party Android training materials. That help?

Comment: Thanks! I hope Nanne answered help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flaw is that if you have a `layoutname.xml` for the portrait AND the landscape (so in 2 different directories), you cannot open them both. Although doubleclicking seems to work, you will not see the new file, but the allready opened file.

Workaround seems to be to update. I'm current running a 64 bit version of Eclipse and it does not have that problem anymore.

> Eclipse SDK
>
> Version: 3.7.1 Build id: M20110909-1335

Comment: That seems logical, and would explain why I didn't see anything in my testing - same version of Eclipse. Thanks!